# GZIP Compression & Decompression Issue

Tags: java, gzip, compression

Hi I am using GZIP for compression and decompression of strings.

Getting Some Exceptions ! Please Help me out !

```
protected byte[] CompressInputString(String input_string2)
        throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
            input_string2.length());
    System.out.println("Byte Array OS : " + os);
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
    System.out.println("GZIPOutputStream : " + gos);
    gos.write(input_string2.getBytes());
    System.out.println("GZIPOutputStream get bytes: "
            + input_string2.getBytes());
    gos.close();
    byte[] compressed = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    System.out.println("Compressed : " + compressed);
    return compressed;

}

protected String DecompressInputString(byte[] input_to_decode_from_function)
        throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input_to_decode_from_function);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
        string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
    }
    gis.close();
    is.close();
    return string.toString();
}
```

My input is : `abcdefghijklmnop`

The output is

```
GZIPOutputStream : java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream@f38798
GZIPOutputStream get bytes: [B@4b222f
Compressed : [B@b169f8
Compressed File : [B@b169f8
```

To uncompress, what input do I give?

If I put `[B@b169f8` as string input and convert it to byte array using input.getBytes() and pass it to my decompress function, an exception is raised

[image: NOT IN GZIP FORMAL EXCEPTION LOG]

Comment: First suggestion: *never* use `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding...

Comment: so what is the second option sir , i need to get this code rolling asap !

Comment: That wasn't an "option" - it was just *part* of what's wrong. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IF I PUT [B@b169f8 as string input and convert it to byte array using INPUT.getBytes() and pass it to my decompress function ... A EXCEPTION IS RAISED

Well yes - because "[B@b169f8" isn't actually the *content* of the byte array. It's just the result of calling `toString()` on it; it's basically indicating the type of the object and its hash.

If you want to convert a byte array into a string in a lossless way, you need to use something like base64. There are lots of libraries which perform base64 encoding, including [this public domain one](http://iharder.net/base64).

Additionally, I would *strongly* advise against using either `String.getBytes()` or the `String(byte[], int, int)` constructors. You should *always* specify an encoding. The simplest way of reading the data would be to create an `InputStreamReader` wrapping the `GZIPInputStream`, and read text data directly from that. I'd suggest using UTF-8 as an encoding for the initial text-to-binary conversion (and on the decompression side too, of course).

Comment: Could you add a code for your suggestion , example - Compression and uncompression functions , PLEASE

Comment: @rolling.stones: No, I'm afraid I don't have time. I've explained what the problems are, and given a pointer to a base64 encoder/decoder. If you have *specific* further questions, I can answer them.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : Could you rectify my mistake in the added comment below for compression and decompression calling ! MY COMPRESSION LOOKS FINE , what input and how do i call , to get my output ?

Comment: **THE MAJOR ISSUE IS , IF THIS APPLICATION IS RUNNING ON 2 COMPUTERS .... I COMPRESS THE STRING ON COMP1 , I WANT TO INSERT THIS COMPRESSED VALUE INTO COMP2 TO GET THE ORIGINAL STRING ON COMP2. WHAT SHOULD BE MY INPUT IN COMP2 TO DECOMPRESS?**

Comment: @rolling.stones: Please stop writing in caps. Your compression is *not* fine, as it uses the platform default encoding, which can vary from place to place. After you've fixed that, you need to transfer the *binary data* returned by `CompressInputString` (you should read up on Java naming conventions, by the way) to the other computer. Currently it sounds like you're trying to do that by calling `toString` on the byte array. As I've explained in my answer, that's basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're turning your byte array into a string using `.toString()` on the byte array, which returns a representation of its memory address, not its contents.

You'll want a reasonable way to represent your byte array as a string, if you really do need it as a string in between.  Base64 is a reasonable way to do this.

Then, you'll need to turn it back into a byte array before feeding it to the inflator.

Or, you could skip the above two steps and just keep the byte array as a byte array, and feed it directly to the inflator.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine to me, I've tried calling your methods like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Test tf = new Test();
    byte[] compressed = tf.CompressInputString("Jimmy");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compressed));
    String s = tf.DecompressInputString(compressed);
    System.out.println(s);//Prints "Jimmy"

}
```

Can you add an example of how you call the methods, and also a complete stack trace of any exception?

Comment: **Decompression** `input_string_for_decode = input_to_decode.getText();     input_string_for_decode_bytes = input_string_for_decode       .getBytes();
decompressed = DecompressInputString(input_string_for_decode_bytes);
     lblDecodedString.setText("Decoded Value : " + decompressed);`

Comment: **Compression**
`input_string_for_encode = input_to_encode.getText().toString();
    try {
     compressed = CompressInputString(input_string_for_encode);
     lblEncodedString.setText("Encoded Value : "
       + compressed.toString());
     System.out.println("Compressed File : " + compressed);
     input_to_decode.setText(compressed.toString());`